# Issue with HTTP request in Objective C

Tags: iphone

Iam trying to submit values to an external DB using http request

My code is below

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=%@&child=%@&content=%@",userId,childId, crackContent.text];

  responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
  NSString *hostStr = @"http://myhost.com/addItem.php?";
  post = [utilityObj getEncodedUrl:post];
  hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
  NSLog(hostStr);

  NSLog(hostStr);
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];

  [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

My issue is that if any space contains any of the parameter it will not submitted, otherwise it is successfully submitted.

Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the parameter encoded before send.

```
NSString* escapedUrlString =
   [unescapedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                        NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Alternative

```
  NSString * escapedUrlString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)unescapedString,
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

Comment: Thaks for your reply, now i can solve the space issue, but when i adding single quotes there is a run time exception happens, u know whts the issue.

Comment: Add another method in answer. You can try.

Comment: Hi WaiLam Thank you for your reply,I applied the second code, and i added a single quote ,now no run time exception, but the data cannot posted.